# unable to show Global Permissions and new LDAP users not able to login

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

we have upgraded from 4.0 to 4.5.4 SonarQube. When a new ldap user is trying to login or an administrator tries to show Global Permissions in the settings menu a JDBCError occurs.

Here the error, that occurs, when I want to show global permissions:

```html
2015.04.23 17:35:49 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9100-exec-5 web[sql]  1ms Executed SQL: SELECT role FROM "group_roles" WHERE (resource_id is null and (group_id is null or group_id in(2,1,
3)))
2015.04.23 17:35:49 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9100-exec-5 web[sql]  0ms Executed SQL: SELECT * FROM "user_roles" WHERE ("user_roles".user_id = 2)
2015.04.23 17:35:49 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9100-exec-5 web[sql]  1ms Executed SQL: SELECT "user_roles"."id" AS t0_r0, "user_roles"."user_id" AS t0_r1, "user_roles"."resource_id" AS t
0_r2, "user_roles"."role" AS t0_r3, "users"."id" AS t1_r0, "users"."name" AS t1_r1, "users"."password" AS t1_r2, "users"."email" AS t1_r3, "users"."created" AS t1_r4, "users"."fullna
me" AS t1_r5, "users"."creationdate" AS t1_r6, "users"."disabled" AS t1_r7, "users"."lastactivation" AS t1_r8, "users"."link" AS t1_r9, "users"."accountreactivation" AS t1_r10, "user
s"."category" AS t1_r11, "users"."email" AS t1_r12, "users"."firstname" AS t1_r13, "users"."lastname" AS t1_r14, "users"."login" AS t1_r15, "users"."password" AS t1_r16, "users"."pho
neno" AS t1_r17, "users"."warehouseholderno" AS t1_r18, "users"."login" AS t1_r19, "users"."name" AS t1_r20, "users"."email" AS t1_r21, "users"."crypted_password" AS t1_r22, "users".
"salt" AS t1_r23, "users"."created_at" AS t1_r24, "users"."updated_at" AS t1_r25, "users"."remember_token" AS t1_r26, "users"."remember_token_expires_at" AS t1_r27, "users"."active"
AS t1_r28 FROM "user_roles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users".id = "user_roles".user_id WHERE ("user_roles"."role" = 'profileadmin' AND "user_roles"."resource_id" IS NULL AND "users
"."active" = 't')
2015.04.23 17:35:49 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9100-exec-5 web[sql]  1ms Executed SQL: select 1
2015.04.23 17:35:49 ERROR http-bio-0.0.0.0-9100-exec-5 web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to render: http://build:9100/roles/global
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: column users.password does not exist
  Position: 184: SELECT "user_roles"."id" AS t0_r0, "user_roles"."user_id" AS t0_r1, "user_roles"."resource_id" AS t0_r2, "user_roles"."role" AS t0_r3, "users"."id" AS t1_r0, "users"
."name" AS t1_r1, "users"."password" AS t1_r2, "users"."email" AS t1_r3, "users"."created" AS t1_r4, "users"."fullname" AS t1_r5, "users"."creationdate" AS t1_r6, "users"."disabled"
AS t1_r7, "users"."lastactivation" AS t1_r8, "users"."link" AS t1_r9, "users"."accountreactivation" AS t1_r10, "users"."category" AS t1_r11, "users"."email" AS t1_r12, "users"."first
name" AS t1_r13, "users"."lastname" AS t1_r14, "users"."login" AS t1_r15, "users"."password" AS t1_r16, "users"."phoneno" AS t1_r17, "users"."warehouseholderno" AS t1_r18, "users"."l
ogin" AS t1_r19, "users"."name" AS t1_r20, "users"."email" AS t1_r21, "users"."crypted_password" AS t1_r22, "users"."salt" AS t1_r23, "users"."created_at" AS t1_r24, "users"."updated
_at" AS t1_r25, "users"."remember_token" AS t1_r26, "users"."remember_token_expires_at" AS t1_r27, "users"."active" AS t1_r28 FROM "user_roles"  LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users".id
 = "user_roles".user_id WHERE ("user_roles"."role" = 'profileadmin' AND "user_roles"."resource_id" IS NULL AND "users"."active" = 't')
        On line #37 of app/views/roles/global.html.erb

    34:         <%= message("global_permissions.#{permission_key}.desc") -%>
    35:           36:           37:         <span id="users-<%= permission_key.parameterize -%>"><%= users(permission_key).map(&:name).join(', ') -%>
    38:         (<%= link_to_edit_roles_permission_form(message('select'), permission_key, nil, "select-users-#{permission_key}") -%>)<br/>
    39:           40:      
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:212:in `log'
    gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in `execute'
    gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:275:in `select'
    gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:202:in `jdbc_select_all'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:60:in `select_all_with_query_cache'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:81:in `cache_sql'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:60:in `select_all_with_query_cache'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1624:in `select_all_rows'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1401:in `find_with_associations'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1268:in `catch'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1399:in `find_with_associations'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:1580:in `find_every'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:619:in `find'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:639:in `all'
    app/helpers/roles_helper.rb:24:in `users'
    app/views/roles/global.html.erb:37
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    app/views/roles/global.html.erb:27
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
```

and here the error that occurs while login:

```html
2015.04.24 10:35:28 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9100-exec-22 web[sql]  3ms Executed SQL: SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."login" = 'a428774') LIMIT 1
2015.04.24 10:35:28 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9100-exec-22 web[sql]  6ms Executed SQL: SELECT * FROM "groups" WHERE ("groups"."name" = 'sonar-users') LIMIT 1
2015.04.24 10:35:28 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9100-exec-22 web[sql]  53ms Executed SQL:  SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname FROM pg_class seq, pg_attribute attr, pg_depend dep, pg_namespa
ce name, pg_constraint cons WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid AND seq.relkind = 'S' AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid AND a
ttr.attnum = cons.conkey[1] AND cons.contype = 'p' AND dep.refobjid = '"users"'::regclass
2015.04.24 10:35:28 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9100-exec-22 web[sql]  2ms Executed SQL: INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "password", "email", "created", "fullname", "creationdate", "disabled
", "lastactivation", "link", "accountreactivation", "category", "firstname", "lastname", "login", "phoneno", "warehouseholderno", "crypted_password", "salt", "created_at", "updated_a
t", "remember_token", "remember_token_expires_at", "active") VALUES('MUSTERMANN, Marc', NULL, 'marc.mustermann@company.com', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'a4
28774', NULL, NULL, 'e285ed59429a05e40b250577fee291addedd09a1', '708e1dc34acb880756709e8db0d66999672478dc', '2015-04-24 10:35:28.400000', '2015-04-24 10:35:28.400000', NULL, NULL, 't
') RETURNING "id"
2015.04.24 10:35:28 ERROR http-bio-0.0.0.0-9100-exec-22 web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to render: http://build:9100/sessions/login
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: column "password" of relation "users" does not exist
  Position: 30: INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "password", "email", "created", "fullname", "creationdate", "disabled", "lastactivation", "link", "accountreactivation", "category", "fir
stname", "lastname", "login", "phoneno", "warehouseholderno", "crypted_password", "salt", "created_at", "updated_at", "remember_token", "remember_token_expires_at", "active") VALUES(
'MUSTERMANN, Marc', NULL, 'marc.mustermann@company.com', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'a428774', NULL, NULL, 'e285ed59429a05e40b250577fee291addedd09a1', '708
e1dc34acb880756709e8db0d66999672478dc', '2015-04-24 10:35:28.400000', '2015-04-24 10:35:28.400000', NULL, NULL, 't') RETURNING "id"
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:212:in `log'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in `execute'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:275:in `select'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:212:in `select_one'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:19:in `selec
t_value'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/postgresql/adapter.rb:266:in `pg_insert'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:26:in `insert_with_q
uery_dirty'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:2967:in `create'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:53:in `create_with_timestamps'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:266:in `create_with_callbacks'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:2933:in `create_or_update'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:250:in `create_or_update_with_callbacks'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:2583:in `save'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1089:in `save_with_validation'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:79:in `save_with_dirty'
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `tran
saction'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save_with_transactions'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save_with_transactions'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/lib/need_authentication.rb:157:in `synchronize'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `tran
saction'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/lib/need_authentication.rb:122:in `synchronize'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/lib/need_authentication.rb:79:in `external_auth'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/lib/need_authentication.rb:101:in `auth'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/lib/need_authentication.rb:56:in `authenticate?'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/lib/need_authentication.rb:236:in `authenticate'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:30:in `login'
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in `perform_action'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
        /global/apps/java.build.sonartest/sonarqube-4.5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
```

Here the plugins we use:

```html
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest     105 23. Apr 09:30 README.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest 2404852 23. Apr 09:31 sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest   10325 23. Apr 09:30 sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest 6228395 23. Apr 09:31 sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest 2507184 23. Apr 09:31 sonar-java-plugin-3.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest   30646 23. Apr 09:31 sonar-ldap-plugin-1.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest 3154834 23. Apr 12:33 sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest 3568440 23. Apr 09:31 sonar-pmd-plugin-2.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest   15342 23. Apr 09:31 sonar-useless-code-tracker-plugin-1.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest  340834 23. Apr 09:31 sonar-web-plugin-2.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsonar jtest   13488 23. Apr 09:30 sonar-widget-lab-plugin-1.6.jar
```

For more information please look at the sonar.properties.

thanks in advance

Regards
Gaby

sonar.properties

```html
# This file must contain only ISO 8859-1 characters.
# See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)
#
# Property values can:
# - reference an environment variable, for example sonar.jdbc.url= ${env:SONAR_JDBC_URL}
# - be encrypted. See http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/settings-encryption.html


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT: the embedded H2 database is used by default. It is recommended for tests but not for
# production use. Supported databases are MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQLServer.

# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonartest

#----- Embedded Database (default)
# It does not accept connections from remote hosts, so the
# server and the analyzers must be executed on the same host.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar

# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9092


#----- MySQL 5.x
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance


#----- Oracle 10g/11g
# - Only thin client is supported
# - Only versions 11.2.* of Oracle JDBC driver are supported, even if connecting to lower Oracle versions.
# - The JDBC driver must be copied into the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/
# - If you need to set the schema, please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE


#----- PostgreSQL 8.x/9.x
# If you don't use the schema named "public", please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://sonartest:5432/test


#----- Microsoft SQLServer 2005/2008
# Only the distributed jTDS driver is supported.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor


#----- Connection pool settings
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER

# Web server is executed in a dedicated Java process. By default its heap size is 768Mb.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options. Enabling the HotSpot Server VM
# mode (-server) is recommended.
# Note that the option -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 is mandatory.
#sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings
# like -Djava.awt.headless=true
#sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
#sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=

# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
sonar.web.port=9100

# TCP port for incoming HTTPS connections. Disabled when value is -1 (default).
#sonar.web.https.port=-1

#
# Recommendation for HTTPS
#    SonarQube natively supports HTTPS. However using a reverse proxy
#    infrastructure is the recommended way to set up your SonarQube installation
#    on production environments which need to be highly secured.
#    This allows to fully master all the security parameters that you want.

# HTTPS - the alias used to for the server certificate in the keystore.
# If not specified the first key read in the keystore is used.
#sonar.web.https.keyAlias=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the server certificate from the
# specified keystore file. The default value is "changeit".
#sonar.web.https.keyPass=changeit

# HTTPS - the pathname of the keystore file where is stored the server certificate.
# By default, the pathname is the file ".keystore" in the user home.
# If keystoreType doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.keystoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified keystore file. The default
# value is the value of sonar.web.https.keyPass.
#sonar.web.https.keystorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of keystore file to be used for the server certificate.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the keystore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the keystore type is used (see sonar.web.https.keystoreType).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreProvider=

# HTTPS - the pathname of the truststore file which contains trusted certificate authorities.
# By default, this would be the cacerts file in your JRE.
# If truststoreFile doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.truststoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified truststore file.
#sonar.web.https.truststorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of truststore file to be used.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the truststore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the truststore type is used (see sonar.web.https.truststoreType).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreProvider=

# HTTPS - whether to enable client certificate authentication.
# The default is false (client certificates disabled).
# Other possible values are 'want' (certificates will be requested, but not required),
# and 'true' (certificates are required).
#sonar.web.https.clientAuth=false

# HTTPS - comma separated list of encryption ciphers to support for HTTPS connections.
# If specified, only the ciphers that are listed and supported by the SSL implementation will be used.
# By default, the default ciphers for the JVM will be used. Note that this usually means that the weak
# export grade ciphers, for instance RC4, will be included in the list of available ciphers.
# The ciphers are specified using the JSSE cipher naming convention (see
# https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html)
# Example: sonar.web.https.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
#sonar.web.https.ciphers=

# The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
# When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until
# the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections
# based on the sonar.web.connections.acceptCount property. The default value is 50 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.maxThreads=50
#sonar.web.https.maxThreads=50

# The minimum number of threads always kept running. The default value is 5 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.minThreads=5
#sonar.web.https.minThreads=5

# The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing
# threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.
# The default value is 25 for each enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.acceptCount=25
#sonar.web.https.acceptCount=25

# Access logs are generated in the file logs/access.log. This file is rolled over when it's 5Mb.
# An archive of 3 files is kept in the same directory.
# Access logs are enabled by default.
#sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=true

# TCP port for incoming AJP connections. Disabled if value is -1. Disabled by default.
#sonar.ajp.port=-1


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SEARCH INDEX

# Elasticsearch is used to facilitate fast and accurate information retrieval.
# It is executed in a dedicated Java process.

# JVM options. Note that enabling the HotSpot Server VM mode (-server) is recommended.
#sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx256m -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
#  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
#  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings
# like -Djava.awt.headless=true
#sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port.
# This port must be private and must not be exposed to the Internet.
sonar.search.port=9102


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# UPDATE CENTER

# Update Center requires an internet connection to request http://update.sonarsource.org
# It is enabled by default.
sonar.updatecenter.activate=true

# HTTP proxy (default none)
http.proxyHost=proxy
http.proxyPort=4711

# NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
#http.auth.ntlm.domain=

# SOCKS proxy (default none)
#socksProxyHost=
#socksProxyPort=

# proxy authentication. The 2 following properties are used for HTTP and SOCKS proxies.
http.proxyUser=proxyuser
http.proxyPassword=proxypwd


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOGGING

# Level of information displayed in the logs: NONE (default), BASIC (functional information)
# and FULL (functional and technical details)
#sonar.log.profilingLevel=NONE

# Path to log files. Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Default is <installation home>/logs
#sonar.path.logs=logs


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OTHERS

# Delay in seconds between processing of notification queue. Default is 60 seconds.
#sonar.notifications.delay=60

# Paths to persistent data files (embedded database and search index) and temporary files.
# Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Defaults are respectively <installation home>/data and <installation home>/temp
#sonar.path.data=data
#sonar.path.temp=temp



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DEVELOPMENT - only for developers
# The following properties MUST NOT be used in production environments.

# Dev mode allows to reload web sources on changes and to restart server when new versions
# of plugins are deployed.
#sonar.web.dev=false

# Path to webapp sources for hot-reloading of Ruby on Rails, JS and CSS (only core,
# plugins not supported).
#sonar.web.dev.sources=/path/to/server/sonar-web/src/main/webapp

# Uncomment to enable the Elasticsearch HTTP connector, so that ES can be directly requested through
# http://lmenezes.com/elasticsearch-kopf/?location=http://localhost:9010
#sonar.search.httpPort=9010


#-------------------
# Sonar LDAP Plugin
#-------------------

# LDAP configuration
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.security.savePassword=true
sonar.authenticator.createUsers=true
sonar.security.updateUserAttributes=true
sonar.security.localUsers=admin,analysers

ldap.url=ldap://ldap.company.com

# (optional) Bind DN is the username of an LDAP user to connect (or bind) with.
ldap.bindDn: cn=ldap,ou=oudaten,DC=company,DC=com
# (optional) Bind Password is the password of the user to connect with.
ldap.bindPassword: pwdldap

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=CN=Users, DC=company,DC=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

# Group Configuration
#ldap.group.baseDn=ou=Groups,dc=sonarsource,dc=com
#ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Properties aelterer Versionen des LDAP-Plugins
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Login Attribute is the attribute in LDAP holding the userÃ¢??s login.
# Default is Ã¢??uidÃ¢??. Set Ã¢??sAMAccountNameÃ¢?? for Microsoft Active Directory
#ldap.user.loginAttribute: sAMAccountName

# Object class of LDAP users.
# Default is 'inetOrgPerson'. Set Ã¢??userÃ¢?? for Microsoft Active Directory.
#ldap.user.objectClass: user


sonar.log.profilingLevel=FULL
```

Comment: Kindly read your own logs before asking us to do it for you: "ERROR: column users.password does not exist". That should be a clue.

Comment: Hi J. Steen, I have seen this line. Thank you. I attached the logs for more informations. It seems, the sql-Statement is not correct. That is the problem. I installed a new sonarqube 5.1 with all the plugins and the columns in the table users are the same. But no error occurs.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause. The database schema must be the only schema in the database. Otherwise this error occurs.